# How to create combinations of subsets, such that the final set does not have repeating elements

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to create a subset of a list, covering every possible combination with the condition that final output is the same length as the initial list and there are no repeating elements.

For the list:

```
X <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

All the non-null subsets are (let's call it `Y`):

```
[('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), 
('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 
'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]
```

What I am looking for is combinations of `Y` such that the elements within the combination are distinct values of `X`.

The acceptable combinations would be:

```
(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),)
(('A',), ('B', 'C', 'D'))
(('B',), ('A', 'C', 'D'))
(('C',), ('A', 'B', 'D'))
(('D',), ('A', 'B', 'C'))
(('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'))
(('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D'))
(('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'))
(('A',), ('B',), ('C', 'D'))
(('A',), ('C',), ('B', 'D'))
(('A',), ('D',), ('B', 'C'))
(('B',), ('C',), ('A', 'D'))
(('B',), ('D',), ('A', 'C'))
(('C',), ('D',), ('A', 'B'))
(('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',))
```

I have tried estimating all possible combinations of `Y` and then getting the length of the distinct values of each combination.

If the `length(distinct elements of combination) = length(X)` then I keep the combination. But this isn't an optimal method by any means and does not cover repeating scenarios.

Also, in my real world scenario, I have up to 40 distinct elements in `X`.

Comment: This is just the number of ways of decomposing the elements of the set, or partitioning with the order of elements not being taken into consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the partitions of an $n$ element set. They are counted by the Bell numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

The $40$th Bell number is pretty big.

If you need this in a computer program, there may be a library in your language. A search for `set partitions python` finds several stackexchange links.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome. If I'd read your question more carefully I might have suggested searching for set partitions in R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partitions/vignettes/setpartitions.pdf